# iOS 11.2.5 - didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken - no response

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, remote-notifications, silentpush

Starting with the OS 11.2.5 my devices weren't able to register a remote notification (e.g. for silent push purposes. I implemented the registration process within these code lines:

```
// Ask for notification permission
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {(accepted, error) in
    if !accepted {
        print("Notification access denied.")
    }
}
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Additionally, as you already know, you need to implement the following two methods, in order to register a remote notification at Apple:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    // Get my token here and do additionally stuff
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // Handling error for registering here
}
```

So my question would be the following: This implementation has been working until Apple OS Update 11.2.4: The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` was successfully called after registering a device and in case of an error the other method `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` was called -> everything perfect!

**But starting with OS 11.2.5** I got no response from Apple anymore. I spent a lot of time investigating this issue. After Apple released OS 11.2.6 it worked like charm again -> I'm totally confused.

**Does anybody know, if this is a known issue in OS 11.2.5?** - Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem caused at registering for remote notification, try below code please:

```
// Ask for notification permission
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {(accepted, error) in
    if accepted {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }else{
        print("Notification access denied.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No this was not the cause, I'll ask for permission at every APP start. It doesn't matter if you call the registerForRemoteNotification inside or outside the requestAuthorization block

Comment: Aha, Sorry for this misunderstand. So you should put this code at :  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func.

Answer (score 0):

```
use updated methods.


// Push Notifications
    func registerForPushnotifications(application: UIApplication)
    {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                guard granted else{ return }
                self.getNotificationSetting()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
                types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        }
    }
    // Push Notification settings
    func getNotificationSetting()
    {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {return}
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Push Notifications Delegates

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
    {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("Failed to register for remote Notifications due to: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What line of code solves the issue within iOS 11.2.5 ?

Comment: if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                guard granted else{ return }
                self.getNotificationSetting()
            }
        }

Comment: its working on every ios in my app :) 
ios 9 - 11.2.5